# Can a C++ concept check that a type is compatible with any type of another concept?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts

I want to create a concept `Handler` that will check that implementers are able to accept any types that satisfy the concept `Update` - without actually having to instantiate the concept with every single possible update object that I have. In my head, it would look something like this:

```
template <typename T>
concept Update = requires (T update) {
  { update.get_value(); } -> std::same_as<std::string>;
  ...
};

template <typename T>
concept Handler = requires (T handler, Update update) {
  handler.on_update(update);
};
```

However this doesn't actually work unless I add an additional parameter to the `Handler` concept and pass a specific instance of the `Update` concept. Is there any way to achieve what I'm trying to do? I have considered creating a mock `FakeUpdate` object that implements the `Update` concept (which is really what I'm hoping the compiler will do), but that feels a little ugly.

Comment: I think creating a mock `Update` is the way to go, because the `requires` statement defining `Update` can be arbitrarily complex. Checking if given `T` satisfies the `requires` statement is infinitely simpler than "create me a `T` that satisfies the `requires` statement".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example shows a bit of a hacky way to achieve what you want.
We simply define the `UpdateableDummy` struct, and pass it to our `Handleable` concept. It would be nice if the `Handleable` concept could deduce the type passed to `on_update` from the template of the `Handleable` class, but this would fail for classes that are *indeed* `Handleable` but not templates (see `non_templateHandleableExample`). So perhaps in a future language standard, the type of the call to `on_update` in the `Handleable` concept, could be deduced from the class being checked for `Handleable`lity

It should also be noted, that `template <Updateable T>` in the declaration of `HandleableExample` requires that `T` be `Updateable`.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <concepts>

template <typename T>
concept Updateable = requires (T update) {
  { update.get_value() } -> std::same_as<std::string>;
};

// Updateable Dummy Type
struct UpdateableDummy {
    std::string get_value(void) {
        return "dummyValue";
    }
};

template <typename U, typename V>
concept Handleable = requires (U handler, V updateableInstance) {
    handler.on_update(updateableInstance);
};

// Updateable Example Type
struct UpdateableExample {
    std::string get_value(void) {
        return "exampleValue";
    }
};

// Not Updateable Example Type
struct NotUpdateableExample {
    void print_value(void) {
        std::cout << "dummyValue\n";
    }
};

// Handleable Example Type
template <Updateable T>
struct HandleableExample {
    void on_update(T t) {
        t.get_value();
    }
};

// Not Handleable Example Type
template <Updateable T>
struct NotHandleableExample {
    void when_update(T t) {
        t.get_value();
    }
};

// Handleable Struct that doesn't use templates
struct non_templateHandleableExample {
    void on_update(UpdateableExample updateableInstance) {
        updateableInstance.get_value();
    }
};

// Works With Both UpdateableDummy and UpdateableExample Type
static_assert(Handleable<HandleableExample<UpdateableDummy>,UpdateableDummy>);
static_assert(Handleable<HandleableExample<UpdateableExample>,UpdateableExample>);

// Works with non_templateHandleableExample
static_assert(Handleable<non_templateHandleableExample,UpdateableExample>);

// Fails For not updateable inner-type
static_assert(Handleable<HandleableExample<NotUpdateableExample>,NotUpdateableExample>);

// Fails For not handleable outer-type
static_assert(Handleable<NotHandleableExample<UpdateableDummy>,UpdateableDummy>);

// Fails For not handleable outer-type AND not updateable inner-type
static_assert(Handleable<NotHandleableExample<NotUpdateableExample>,NotUpdateableExample>);


int main()
{
  // Comment out intentionally failing static assertions to test the auto type keyword example
  Handleable<UpdateableExample> auto handleableInstance = HandleableExample<UpdateableExample>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is mostly what I was envisioning when I talked about creating a mock `Update` object but accepting because it seems what I want is not possible.